# Is there a way to state $\limsup_{n\to\infty}{x_n}=x$ using "\forall"

Tags: limits, logic, limsup-and-liminf

Denote $\{x_n\}$ as a sequence of real numbers, and there exist a $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$\limsup_{n\to\infty}{x_n}=x$.
We can write "$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$"
as "$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N} ,s.t\quad n\geq N\Rightarrow|x_n-x|<\epsilon$".
So I wonder if it's possible for the "$\limsup$".

> Is there a way to state $\limsup_{n\to\infty}{x_n}=x$ by "$\forall$" and "$\exists$"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just write down the definition in words. That will tell you how to write it with symbols for the quantifiers. You may need more than two of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. Here is one way. The definition of $\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$ consists of two parts:

1. That there are elements of $x_n$ that get arbitrarily close to $x$ for arbitrarily large $n$
2. That $x$ is the largest such number.

So, with that in mind, let's see if we can write something down. For part 1:
$$
\forall N\in \Bbb N, \varepsilon >0\,\exists n>N s.t. |x_n-x|<\varepsilon
$$
And then the second part. It's going to be a bit longer, but the idea is that $x$ is the largest number satisfying the above relation. Thus any $y$ which satisfies it must be less than or equal to $x$. If you keep that in mind, it ought to be readable:
$$
\forall y\in \Bbb R\Big(\forall N\in \Bbb N, \varepsilon >0\,\exists n>N s.t. |x_n-y|<\varepsilon\implies y\leq x\Big)
$$
Sticking these two statements together with a $\land$ should get you a nice symbolic definition of
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n = x
$$

From this it is also easy to define $\liminf$ by simply switching the inequality in the second statement.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea No, it is indeed the largest such number, not the smallest. Just like regular $\sup$ of some set is the largest number which is arbitrarily close to elements of the set.

Comment: Sorry for my rudeness. I think it's clear for me now. Would you mind cosidering whether it's possible to simplify its form?

Comment: @Oolongmilktea One could rewrite the second statement into something like $$\forall y>x\,\exists N\in \Bbb N, \varepsilon >0\,\forall n>N\, |x_n-y|\geq \varepsilon$$which gets rid of the implication. But other than that I don't see much one can do. The number of quantifiers needed to express an idea is not easy to do anything about, and other than the quantifiers, the expressions are very simple. And it's not easy to express ideas 1 and 2 in the same statement either, as they do separate jobs of giving upper and lower bounds on $x$.

Answer (score 2):

$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists n_0,n_1,n_2,... s.t. n_1<n_2<... , \forall n \geq n_o, \forall k, x_n \leq x+\epsilon, x_{n_k} >x-\epsilon $

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I sometimes get confused with ellipsis.